# Cannot sort out *current* information on crazy MongoDB Memory Usage

Tags: mongodb

There a a million threads on this, all super confusing because there's still a ton of threads about mmap or wiredTiger, and it's a huge buffet of confusion.

I'll be brief -

MongoDB 3.6 on a machine with 32g, wiredTiger, cache set to 12g, my database is 800M on disk compressed, and db.stats() tells me it's about 3.7G in memory.  However within minutes of starting, `mongod` runs up to appx 27 of the available 32G on the server, and slowly creeps up for a few more hours until it starts swapping and is OOM killed.

How in the wide world can I discover why a 4G database is taking 30+G in RAM?

Answer (score 0):

Some key areas you'll want to investigate are the following:

1. Start reviewing the log file looking for operations that aren't indexed well or are performing collection scans.
2. Look for any operations that are just slow and figure out why (resource contention? locking? etc.)
3. Aggregations and/or MapReduce operations can consume huge amounts of memory depending on what the operations are doing. A large number of these operation would require duplicating a ton of data in memory and easily explain the large amount of memory usage you're seeing.

You should also look at what version of MongoDB you're running and figure out if a patch is appropriate. Minor versions sometime include fixes that deal with cache or memory management.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful steps.  Sadly I've done all these things.  The questions I cannot seem to get answered are - a) *why* (technically) would it ever grow larger than the sum total of all data including indexes in memory and b) how to make it stop.  I get that "processing" may require more memory than all the data, but not literally 10 times more.